# Changing function signature

Tags: python

My assignment is to use two functions to (a) reverse a number and (b) to check whether the number that was just reversed is a palindrome of itself.

```
 number = eval(input("enter number: "))
 reverse(number)



 def reverse(number):
     reversed = int(str(number)[::-1])
     isPalindrome(number,reversed)

 def isPalindrome(number,reversed):
     if reversed == number:
     print("the number",number,"is a palindrome.")

 else:
    print("the number",number,"is NOT a palindrome.")
```

This code works just fine, but my professor wants both functions to only accept 'number' as a parameter, and not number and reversed as I have. I'm not quiet sure how I would go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: [DONT USE `eval`](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) Use `int` there. Apart from that there are serious indentation issues here. Please try to correct them

Comment: Both `reverse` and `isPalindrome` may as well take a string as an argument. It doesn't make sense to ask if a number is a palindrome, only if its representation in a specific base is. One hundred ninety five is not a palindrome in base 10 (195) or base 16 (C3), but it is as an unsigned binary number (11000011).

Answer (score 0):

You can use arguments to pass inputs to functions, and use the `return` keyword to get outputs from functions

```
def reverse(number):
    return ''.join(str(number)[::-1])

def isPalindrome(number):
    return str(number) == reverse(number)
```

Example

```
>>> isPalindrome(100)
False
>>> isPalindrome(5005)
True
```

Comment: in reverse function `str(number)[::-1]` is enough, no need to use join

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast to int at all, you call call `reverse` in `isPalindrome`, all you need to pass is the input string:

```
def reverse(number):
    return number[::-1] # return string reversed

def isPalindrome(number):
    if reverse(number) == number: # compare reversed string to original
        print("the number", number, "is a palindrome.")
    else:
        print("the number", number, "is NOT a palindrome.")


number = input("enter number: ")
isPalindrome(number)
```